# COPY HEADER available only in CSV mode

Tags: postgresql

When I try to use the `COPY` command with `HEADER` option and format `text` to export a table in postgreSQL, I get the following error:

> COPY HEADER available only in CSV mode

I understand that we can use format `CSV` with a different delimiter than `,` to generate a different file format, but I am wondering why the use of `HEADER` with `text` format is prohibited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `text` format of `COPY` is proprietary to PostgreSQL and not very useful for data exchange with other software. For example, a NULL value is represented as `\N`.

Since nobody saw a need for having header data in this format, it didn't get implemented.

Use the `csv` format for data exchange.